# Git Bash: warning - как вернуть все в первозданный вид?

Tags: git, git-bash

Здраствуйте!
Сегодня первый день осваиваю git. Несколько раз создала и удалила файлы. Все сломала))) Помогите поправить.
[image: screen git-bash]

Comment: Сегодня первый день читаю ваш вопрос. Несколько раз прочитал, ничего не понял. Помогите понять

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уважаемая user385674, я постараюсь Вам помочь, дав пару коротких советов.

К сожалению, Ваш вопрос могут закрыть за "неконкретность". Но это не беда - Мы можете его уточнить и открыть заново.

Как я вижу на скриншоте, Вы ничего не сломали.

Вы заходите в домашнюю директорию.

Говорите git status

Статус говорит "много всего", в том числе - что коммитить нечего (последняя строка) и что ряд директорий недоступны из за прав (наверное, это правда)

Дело в том, что использовать git в корне домашней директори - не имеет смысла.

git - это штука, предназначенная для контроля версий проекта.

Проект в нём ассоциируется с директорией.

Поэтому первое, что нужно сделать - это создать директорию, в которой будет находиться проект.

После этого - создавать, удалять, помещать в git и т.п. файлы, находящиеся в этйо директории.

Использование git в корневой домашней директории - это, наверное, плохая идея. Если исключить совсем уж экзотические случаи.

Вы можете уточнить вопрос, и на более конкретный вопрос Вам, скорее всего, ответят!